# .htaccess - redirect between two react apps

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have two react apps in the same subdomain - in different directories.

1. app.domain.com
2. app.domain.com/login

For react router to work I have existing `.htaccess` rules to redirect all traffic to the app (index.html)

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /

#Not sure what this does
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^open&guid= 
RewriteRule ^ ? [R=301,L,NE]

#Not sure what this does
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]

#Redirect all to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I want to allow to load the react app in directory `/login` **and** redirect all `/login/*` requests to `/login/index.html`.

How can I apply these rules using `.htaccess`?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing .htaccess is fine. Just create another `.htaccess` under `/login/` directory as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect all to index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.html [L]
```

This will route every non-file and non-directory `/login/*` request to `/login/index.html`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing URLs.

```
RewriteRule ^login/?$  login/index.html [NC,L]
```

---

---

OR uri has starting login with having other things in uri.

```
RewriteRule ^login(?!=index\.html)  login/index.html [NC,L]
```